# python3 finds some programs in a folder, but not others

Tags: python, shell

I have the following directory:

```
~/Library/Python/3.9/bin
```

Inside that folder, for example, appear these two programs:

[image]

Executing:

`python3 -m submit50`

gives...

```
usage: submit50 [-h] [--logout] [--log-level {debug,info,warning,error}] [-V]
                slug
...
```

However, executing:

`python3 -m youtube-dl`

gives...

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: No module named youtube-dl
```

What's happening here ?

- Why isn't the program `youtube-dl` being located, and
- Why is the path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/` appearing there ?

**OS: macOS Ventura 13.1**

Comment: Try `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"`. Most probably you have `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/` but don't have `/Library/Python/3.9/bin` there

Comment: Thank you, @Yevhen Kuzmovych ! I'll try that now, but why is `submit50` being located? It's in the exact same folder.

Comment: Maybe `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/` also has `submit50` in it.

Comment: I'll check now.

Comment: Just checked @Yevhen Kuzmovych. `submit50` is not there.

Comment: I added `/Library/Python/3.9/bin` to my path but still no joy.

Comment: Weirdly, the executable seems to be `youtube_dl` (with an underscore)